# Restrict route to only be accessible as redirect from specific action

Tags: playframework, routes

I am using Play 2.4.x for Java

I would like to restrict a particular route to be accessible *only* as a redirect route from another specific action. This is probably more clear with a specific example:

I have a signup POST route:

```
POST        /signup          controllers.Signup.doSignup()
```

In the corresponding action doSignup, I return `redirect(controllers.routes.Signup.onSuccess());` which corresponds to this route:

```
GET         /success             controllers.Signup.onSuccess()
```

But I would like to prevent users from directly accessing this route by issuing a get request to that URL. I *only* want this route accessible via the redirect from doSignup(). Is this possible???

Comment: I think it is possible...
You can use method Global.onRequest() to check wheather you're trying to get to this method from apropriate link.
But you have to keepi it in midn that this method starts whenever you want to get to controllers method

Answer (score 0):

You could try to check the referer of your request in your `controllers.Signup.onSuccess()` action. Although I'm not sure whether Play will set the referer during a redirect. But if Play sets it you can just check it with something like this:

```
if(!request().getHeader("referer").equals("/signup")) {
  return forbidden();
}
```